# AutoMapper add Profile on assembly load

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to register all the Mappings in my **Business Layer** to **Data Layer**, and **Data Layer** to **Business Layer** classes just as my Business Layer assembly loads.  Currently I am using a static class to do this task for me:

```
public static class AutoMapperBootstrapper
{
    public static void InitMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(a => a.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
    }
}
```

But each time I make a call with Mapper.Map and the added mappings in the profile, it is still saying Missing Type Mapping Information.

**How I should go about fixing this?**

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of the mapping configuration and map call that is failing?

Comment: I am not having an explicit call to Configure method.  Only this call in the Business class:  AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DL.MasterList>, IEnumerable<BL.MasterList>>(sourceData).ToList<MasterList>();

Comment: Could you give us the CreateMap calls in your profile class? Might help suggest where the problem is. I presume you have established that your bootstrapper is being called?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `Mapper.AddProfile` is not calling when the application starts.
Try this,

In `Global.asax.cs` [`Application_Start`],

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mapper.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
}
```

And `MyProfile` looks like below,

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "Name"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        //// BL to DL
        Mapper.CreateMap<BLCLASS, DLCLASS>();

        ////  and DL to BL
        Mapper.CreateMap<DLCLASS, BLCLASS>();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this can be done if my profiles are defined in the web project. But the Profiles are present in Business Layer which maps business Objects with Database Objects. I have written a static class in BusinessLayer with static method to add the Profile, But I am not sure how will I call that static method.

Comment: You can add profiles from other projects in the App_Start method. For example: `AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(a => { a.AddProfile<Business.Layer.MyProfile>(); a.AddProfile<Another.Layer.AnotherProfile>(); });`

Comment: [This blog post](http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2012/08/27/organizing-automappers-map-configurations-in-mvc/) may give some pointers.

Comment: Link within comment by Mightymuke is an excellent read and helped me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have gotten an answer to this yet. You are on the right track, but don't use `Mapper.Initialize`. If you use initialize, you are clearing all of the existing mappings and then adding the ones in the initialize call. Instead just call `AddProfile` in your static method. Or better yet, just add the profile in your constructor of the BL or DL class.

```
public static class AutoMapperBootstrapper
{
    public static void AddMappings()
    {
        Mapper.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
    }
}
```

So in a nutshell, what is happening is you are adding whatever mappings you need for your web tier in the `Global.asax` or wherever you are adding them.  Then the first time your BL or DL is loaded, you are calling initialize which clears any existing mappings. So the next time you go to use a mapping that had already been added, you get the message that it does not exist because it was cleared by the call to initialize.